# RSA vs El Gamal digital signature. Which is more secure?

Tags: rsa, elgamal-signature

I'm reading about the [notions of security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature#Notions_of_security) concerning digital signatures and I can't understand whether RSA is more secure than El Gamal digital signature. Well, they are both prone to forgery, but I don't see which signature is better in terms of security.

Comment: I don't see how that's a duplicate. This question is about RSA and ElGamal *signatures*, the other question about RSA and ElGamal *encryption*.

Comment: Wow, great spot - impressed you looked that far back to old posts!